# Trying to get all Landscan Urban areas in the USA (from Natural World shp files)

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr, ogr2ogr, natural-earth

I'm desperately trying to get a json file of all the Landscan urban areas in the USA.

The ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan.shp has a list containing polygons of all urban areas in the world with a NAME attribute that lists the name of the urban area (i.e. 'Aarhus')

But in order to work out whether that NAME attribute is in the USA, I also need to combine it with data from ne_10m_populated_places.shp which has the name of the city along with the country its in (i.e. 'Aarhus' and 'Denmark').

However, whatever I do I just cannot get the data from both files.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON
  -sql "SELECT ne_10m_populated_places.*, ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan.*
  FROM ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan
  LEFT JOIN 'ne_10m_populated_places.shp'.ne_10m_populated_places
  ON ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan.name_conve = ne_10m_populated_places.NAME"
us-urban_areas.json ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan.shp
```

The above command gets me all the urban areas in the world joined with the populated places data, but its not WHERE country = USA.
If I do put in a WHERE clause then I get an SQL error because I'm filtering based on a field in the populated_places file, not the urbanareas one.

More promisingly...

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON
  -sql "SELECT ne_10m_populated_places.*, ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan.*
  FROM ne_10m_populated_places
  LEFT JOIN 'ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan.shp'.ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan
  ON ne_10m_populated_places.NAME = ne_10m_urban_areas_landscan.name_conve
  WHERE ne_10m_populated_places.ADM0_A3 IN ('USA')"
us-urban_areas.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

The above command returns just the cities in the USA, with all the joined data, except the single Point Geometries from the populated places file are kept and the Polygon geometries from the urban areas file are lost.

I just don't know what to do. Does anyone have any ideas?